# Prove that the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(n!)^n}{e^{n!}}$ does not converge.

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

Prove that the series diverges.
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(n!)^n}{e^{n!}}$$

IT'S SUPPOSED TO BE e^(n!) in the denominator if it isn't clear.

I am having a lot of difficulties with this problem. I want to solve it with the comparison test or ratio test. Any tips?

Thank You

Comment: Did you try the root or ratio tests?

Comment: $\frac{(n!)^n}{e^{n!}} > \frac{(n!)^n}{(e^n)^n}$ is just wrong, how did you come to it?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake thanks for the answer

Comment: I edited the question so that other people can make use of the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(n!)^n}{e^{n!}}$ is **convergent**
by  the [Root test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test): we have that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n!}{e^{(n-1)!}}\leq \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n!}{1+(n-1)!+\frac{1}{2}((n-1)!)^2}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{n!}+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{(n-1)!}{2n}}=0$$
where we used the inequality $e^x\geq 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}$ for $x\geq 0$.

P.S. Your inequality $\frac{(n!)^n}{e^{n!}} > \frac{(n!)^n}{(e^n)^n}$ is wrong because $e^{n!}>e^{n^2}=(e^n)^n$ for $n\geq 4$.

Comment: Thanks I realized my mistake

Comment: @wss Well done.

Comment: Are you sure we can substitute x=(n+1) ! in the maclaurins expansion of e^x?

Comment: Yes. By Taylor's Theorem, for $x>0$ there is $t\in (0,x)$ such that
$e^x= 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+e^t\frac{x^3}{6}$. Hence $e^x\geq 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}$ for ALL $x>0$.

Comment: @wss Any further doubt?

Comment: No. All good Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$$n\log n!-n!\sim n^2\log n-n!<-(n-3)!$$ decreases pretty fast. The series converges.

Comment: this is the same idea as my answer but more precise (and posted before mine) +1

Answer (score 0):

The series converges by root test

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(n!)^n}{e^{n!}}\implies \sqrt[n] {a_n}=\frac{n!}{e^{(n-1)!}}\to 0$$

indeed by squeeze theorem

$$0\le\frac{n!}{e^{(n-1)!}}\le\frac{(n-1!)^2}{e^{(n-1)!}}\to 0$$

Answer (score 0):

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have :
$
e^{n!} = (((e^1)^2)^{...})^n
$

Hence : 
$
\frac{(n!)^n}{e^{n!}} = \left(\frac{n!}{((e^1)^{...})^{n-1}}\right)^n \le \frac{1}{n^n}
$

So this is less than the $\frac{1}{n^2}$ serie which converges,  the serie must diverge